# how to add a class/id attribute to html.beginumbracoform

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, umbraco, umbraco7, html.beginform

I've been trying to add a css style to my `BeginUmbracoForm` but my CSS file cannot find the Class name i've given the `UmbracoForm`? Any answers?

```
using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<UmbRegisterController>("HandleRegisterMember", null, new { @class = "RegisterForm" }))
```

Comment: If this it is a valid answer could you put the questions as answered

Answer (score 4):

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("Action", "Surface", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "YourId" } }))
```

It work for class to

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("Action", "Surface", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "YourId" }, { "class" , "YourClass" } }))
```

Or anything more that you want.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! I just want to add some Css style to my textboxes and labels in the Form. is'nt it any other way to just adding an ID/Class to the Form

Comment: There is you could use the form selector on css but than this would be applied to all your forms.

Comment: For anyone looking for a shorter option, this can also be achieved as follows: `@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("Action", "Surface", null, new { id = "YourId" , @class = "YourClass" }))`